# Keep WCS coordinates when slicing RGB Fits image

Tags: python, image, physics, astronomy, astropy

I've got a collection of RGB Fits images and I want to plot the blue frame with WCS on the axes. I have sliced the image to take the blue using:

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits

image1 = fits.open('fits_file.fits')
data1 = image1[0].data
image1_slice_blue = data1[2,:,:]
```

When I plot this, the axes correspond to the number of pixels and not the WCS coordinates. 
I have tried to take the WCS info from the file using:

```
wcs1 = WCS(image1[0].header)
```

but I have a problem because NAXIS = 3 (image width, height and planes) but WCSAXES = 2 (RA and Dec). The error says 3 dimensions have been detected in the core WCS keywords and tells me to select/reduce the dimensions using the naxis kwarg. I ran this again, but with:

```
wcs1 = WCS(image1[0].header, naxis=2)
```

But this doesn't work either because CTYPE3 not found. Can anyone help me resolve this? Thanks

This is the image I was trying to split: http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/2677994#annotated

I can't share the actual file, but it's the "new-image.fits" file on the RHS.

Comment: Could you provide the file? That way it would be easier to help :)

Comment: @zabop I've put a link to the fits image in the text. The problem comes with the wcs = WCS(hdu1.header) and I can't get my way around that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and found a bug with astropy, https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/10527

Here was my workaround for dealing with datacubes

```py
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

# download image into memory
url = 'https://sha.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/Spitzer/SHA/servlet/ProductDownload?DATASET=level1&ID=382262290'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
hdulist = fits.open(BytesIO(response.read()))

# reproduce bug
try:
    wcs = WCS(hdulist[0].header)
except ValueError:
    hdulist[0].header['NAXIS'] = 2
    wcs = WCS(hdulist[0].header)
```